# Finding Control inside RadGrid FormTemplate

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Let' say I have this grid,

```
<telerik:RadGrid
    ...........................
    ...........................
    <FormTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" />
    </FormTemplate>
    ...........................
    ...........................
    ...........................
```

Now In code behind I need txtDescription inside DataSource1_Updating event,

```
    protected void DataSource1_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e){
```

Is this is possible?

Comment: Sure is possible. What have you tried so far? `FindControl` should get you started.

Comment: @nunespascal, I was able to find this but now I need to get the selected index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this issue. Defined a EditCommand,

```
    protected void RadGrid1_EditCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["CurrentIndex"] = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    }
```

and in my event,

```
protected void DataSource1_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e){

        var currentIndex = (int)ViewState["CurrentIndex"];
        var form = RadGrid1.Items[currentIndex].EditFormItem;
        var txtDescription= form.FindControl("txtDescription") as RadComboBox;
```